# BASH: read in while loop

Tags: bash, loops

```
while [ $done = 0  ]
  do
  echo -n "Would you like to create one? [y/n]: "
  read answer
  if [ "$(answer)" == "y" ] || [ "$(answer)" == "Y" ]; then
    mkdir ./fsm_$newVersion/trace
    echo "Created trace folder in build $newVersion"
    $done=1
  elif [ "$(answer)" == "n" ] || [ "$(answer)" == "N" ]; then
    $done=2
  else
    echo "Not a valid answer"
  fi
done
```

Ok so I have this simple bashscript above that simply just tries to get input from a user and validate it. However I keep getting this error

```
./test.sh: line 1: answer: command not found
./test.sh: line 1: answer: command not found
./test.sh: line 1: answer: command not found
./test.sh: line 1: answer: command not found
```

Which I have no idea why because "answer" is nowhere near line 1. So I ran into this [article](http://fvue.nl/wiki/Bash:_Piped_%60while-read'_loop_starts_subshell)

Which makes sense since it's referring to line 1 and can't find answer. So it seems to be starting a new subshell. However I didn't really understand the solution and can't see how I would apply it to my case. I just wanna get this to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$(answer)` doesn't substitute the value of the variable `answer`.  It executes `answer` as a command, and substitutes the output of that command.  You want `${answer}` everywhere you have `$(answer)`.  In this case you can get away with bare `$answer` too, but overuse of `${...}` is good paranoia.

(Are you perhaps used to writing Makefiles?  `$(...)` and `${...}` are the same in Makefiles, but the shell is different.)

By the way, you have some other bugs:

- In shell, you do not put a dollar sign on the variable name on the left hand side of an assignment.  You need to change `$done=1` to just `done=1` and similarly for `$done=2`.
- You are not being paranoid enough about your variable substitutions.  Unless you *know for a fact* that it does the wrong thing in some specific case, you should *always* wrap *all* variable substitutions in double quotes.  This affects both the `mkdir` command and the condition on the `while` loop.
- You are not being paranoid enough about arguments to `test` (aka `[`).  You need to prefix both sides of an equality test with `x` so that they cannot be misinterpreted as switches.
- `==` is not portable shell, use `=` instead (there is no difference in bash, but many non-bash shells do not support `==` at all).

Put it all together and this is what your script should look like:

```
while [ "x${done}" = x0 ]; do
  echo -n "Would you like to create one? [y/n]: "
  read answer
  if [ "x${answer}" = xy ] || [ "x${answer}" = xY ]; then
    mkdir "./fsm_${newVersion}/trace"
    echo "Created trace folder in build $newVersion"
    done=1
  elif [ "x${answer}" = xn ] || [ "x${answer}" = xN ]; then
    done=2
  else
    echo "Not a valid answer"
  fi
done
```

Comment: Ahh thank you!! I've been battling this for an hour now. This is the first time I've attempted to write a bash script (or any kind of script)

Comment: Glad to be of help.  I expanded the answer a bit, you had some other bugs.

Comment: Oh, also, the reason it's saying "line 1" is because "answer" is on line one *of the nested shell script induced by `$(...)`*.  Yah, that's less than helpful, indeed arguably a bug in the shell.

Comment: I don't really understand what adding the 'x' does.

Comment: If you quote your variables inside `[]` you don't need the archaic "x". And regarding portability, if you're writing a `#!/bin/bash` script, you might as well use `[[]]` and `==` (inside `(())` you *must* use `==` for comparison since `=` is used for assignment).

Comment: @Albinoswordfish: The 'x' defends against the possibility that the variable's value might begin with a dash, which would be interpreted as an option (so, for instance, without the 'x' if $answer was "-e", it might try to test for the existence of a file named "=", which is not what you wanted). @Dennis: Quoting the variables only defends against them expanding to the wrong number of space-separated arguments; it doesn't help with a leading dash. And I don't believe in writing bash-specific shell scripts; if you can't write your shell script portably, you're better off switching to perl.

Comment: I suppose I should hedge even more, and say that yes, *some* shells will do a string comparison for `[ -e = Y ]`, but it's not something one can rely on.

Answer (score 0):

> Which I have no idea why because
>   "answer" is nowhere near line 1. So I
>   ran into this article

That's not your problem here.

I ran the script and did not get the error you got.  I did receive the error:

```
./test.sh: line 1: [: -eq: unary operator expected
```

when I tried to compile though.  Defining done fixed this.  The following script should work...

```
#!/bin/bash

done=0
while [ $done -eq 0 ]
do
  echo -n "Would you like to create one? [y/n]: "
  read answer
  if [[ "$(answer)" == "y" || "$(answer)" == "Y" ]]; then
    mkdir ./fsm_${newVersion}/trace
    echo "Created trace folder in build $newVersion"
    $done=1
  elif [[ "$(answer)" == "n" || "$(answer)" == "N" ]]; then
    $done=2
  else
    echo "Not a valid answer"
  fi
done
```

...note you were doing string comparisons on your done variable, which you apparently intended to be numeric.  It's generally bad form to do string comparison on a numeric type variable, though it will work.  Use -eq (arithmetic comparison operator) instead. (Also note that if you kept that test, your string equality would be inconsistent... you had "=" in one spot and "==" in another spot... nitpicking here, but it's helpful to be consistent).

Also, I suggest double brackets for your compound conditionals as they will be more readable if you have longer ones.  e.g.

```
if [[($var1 -eq 0 && $var2 -eq 1) || ($var1 -eq 1 && $var2 -eq 0)]]; then
```

Just a matter of preference as you only have two conditions, but could be useful in the future.

Also you were missing braces '{' '}' around your newVersion variable.

Finally, I'd suggest putting the line #!/bin/bash on the top of your script.  Otherwise its up to your environment to determine what to do with your script, which is a bad idea.

Comment: Double-bracket tests, sadly, are far less portable than single-bracket tests, which work everywhere as long as you know all of the little tricks (like x-prefixes and not using -a/-o).

Comment: Perhaps, but I think they're much more readable and I haven't run across any major distros that they didn't work on so far that I recall (used Red Hat, CentOS, Ubuntu, and Fedora...)

Comment: You really don't encounter much in the way of shell portability headaches if you limit yourself to Linux.  Poke at OpenSolaris without any of the GNU tools installed and without `/usr/xpg4/bin` in your $PATH, some time.  (And then if your sanity survives that, find yourself an AIX account.)

Comment: Fair enough.  Fortunately I haven't had to go there, though some of our old makefiles at my old job had solaris references (I guess at one point we supported it). :)

Comment: P.S. Care to answer this question of mine, o bash scripting guru? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561326/bash-compound-conditional-with-wildcards-and-file-existence-check